# Code observation as belonging to quantile in Stata

Tags: stata

In Stata, I wanted to be able to put observations in buckets based on a specific variable, or equivalently code observations as belonging to a certain quantile. I looked around for some existing code that would accomplish this task but didn't quite find what I wanted. I wrote the following simple ado:

```
program toquantiles
  version 13
  syntax varname [, n(integer 4)]

  quietly{
    local interval = 100/`n'
    local binVarName = "`varlist'_quantile"
    gen `binVarName' = `n'

    local upper = `n'-1
    forvalues i=1/`upper'{
      local y = `i'*`interval'
      //Abuse the egen cmd to calculate the yth percentile.
      tempvar x
      egen `x' = pctile(`varlist'), p(`y')
      //Label this observation as belonging to the ith bin if the value of the
      //var in question is greater than x.
      replace `binVarName' = `n'-`i' if `varlist' > `x'
      drop `x'
    }
  }
end
```

The output is that each observation has a new variable, varname_quantile that is coded as 1,2,3, etc. based on the quantile in which it fits. My code seems like a pretty naive approach to this problem.

Is there any built-in functionality that does what I do above? If not, are there any improvements to this ado that would speed up execution? Currently, it runs quite slowly. (Slowly as in, it is faster to summ all 100+ variables than to calculate the quintiles for 1 variable.) Thanks so much.

Comment: Did you check `help xtile`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a terminology problem here, most simply illustrated by **quartiles**,  three particular summary statistics, the lower and upper quartiles and the median in between, and the first, second, third and fourth **quarters** (some say quartiles here too), intervals defined by falling below or above particular quartiles. (What happens when values equal particular quartiles is a matter of convention.)

In other words, quartiles and more generally quantiles can be particular **levels** (which I take to be the standard statistical use of the term) or **intervals** (a common (mis?)use of the term in some applied fields, e.g. applied economics).

It seems that you want the second sense.

Turning to Stata, doesn't `xtile` do this?

See also http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/percentile-ranks-and-plotting-positions/index.html

Comment: Thanks, `xtile` was exactly what I was looking for. Not sure how I didn't see that in the documentation.

Comment: A surprising gap is the inability to apply `xtile` easily to multiple subsets, but see the dedicated `egen` function from `egenmore` on SSC.